# Show grouped value for item in table

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two table in a database Inventory and Invoices. I have a report that will show the items and the amount.  What im seeing now below:

```
Name, Item number, Total, Amount Collected, Invoice

John Doe, 10022, $500, 1100, 100023044

John Doe, 10022, $600, 1100, 100023044
```

John can have 2 items on the same invoice. What I'm trying to do is show how much they collected in one column and not the two of them.

What i want to see is

```
John Doe, 10022, $500, 1100, 100023044

John Doe, 10022, $600, **blank**, 100023044
```

I want to see the amount collected group on the report for all the items with multiple items attached to the same invoice

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select Name, Item, Total,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then Amount end) as Amount,
       Invoice
from  (select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by invoice order by amount) as seqnum
       from t
      ) t
order by invoice, seqnum
```